# How can I create a shell context menu like "Play to"? (Dynamic add items)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-explorer, context-menu

I spent 3 hours googling but not answer...

I am noob to windows, and i am creating app that sends files over wifi to nearby devices.I am detecting devices using broadcast.

I need context menu item that works like "Play to", when i hover "Play to", it expands and show local devices where i can stream to my video or music (in my case Smart TV). If i turn off one of TVs, next time i hover Play to, it wont be on list... It scans network and dynamicly add context menu subitems to "Play to" ite, i need it just like that!

I really dont have clue how to this, i have finish all (Java) classes for finding and sending files to local mobile devices , and just need some tip, how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I work with online radio we handle host servers, servers, DJ's from all over the US streaming music to these servers all across the US. We use a broadcasting program. However, what actually streams the music to the individual servers is a program called firebird or an SQL firebird is the easier program. If you have the program to play already figured out all you need is the stream program. Hope that helps.